# Stop sticky sub navigation from jumping into place

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a main fixed navigation but I also have a sub nav that is picked up later on in the page.

When you scroll past the `#secondary-nav` div it adds a class of `.sticky` adding `position:fixed` to the div. However it does this after you have already scrolled passed it then jumps into place under the main navigation. How can I smooth this out so it looks like its being smoothly added as you scroll past it and then placed back again if you scroll up?

**[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fgfb9cpq/).**

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="top-wrapper">I'm a sitcky navigation</nav>
<div id="hero">
hero image!
</div>
<nav id="secondary-nav">
 I'm the secondary nav.
</nav>
<div id="content">
I'm the content, scroll down!
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() === 0) {
    $('#top-wrapper').removeClass('sticky ');
  } else {
    $('#top-wrapper').addClass('sticky ');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
      var nav = $('#secondary-nav');
      if (nav.length) {
          var stickyNavTop = nav.offset().top;
          $(window).scroll(function () {
              if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyNavTop) {
                  $('#secondary-nav').addClass('sticky');
              } else {
                  $('#secondary-nav').removeClass('sticky');
              }
          });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: See the updated fiddle It'S should be ok for you https://jsfiddle.net/fgfb9cpq/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try adding `- 100` in your top offset in your jquery code. Check this fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/fgfb9cpq/1/. and update the `top` in secondary nav.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
      var nav = $('#secondary-nav');
      if (nav.length) {
          var stickyNavTop = nav.offset().top - 100;
          $(window).scroll(function () {
              if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyNavTop) {
                  $('#secondary-nav').addClass('sticky');
              } else {
                  $('#secondary-nav').removeClass('sticky');
              }
          });
      }
    });
});
```